# TextView exceed Constraint if text is too long in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, android-constraintlayout

I have one `TextView` aligned to the left and centered vertically. Two groups of `ImageView` and `TextView` are both aligned to the right, with two layout configurations, one with image on the right, another with image on the left.

The hello world text can be very long. I want it to expand to fill the whole width without covering up the left text.

I have added `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text1"` to constraint the right group (image + text) not to overlap with the left text. However, it does not behave as I expected.

How to make it not overlapping using only ConstraintLayout?

[image: result with short text]

`Text1` will be covered up if the right text is too long, which is not expected. Be noted that the image on the second row is gone too.
[image: result with long text]

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Text1" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/row1_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/row1_image"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Hello World" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/row1_image"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/row1_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_confirm" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_barrier"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="row1_text,row1_image" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/row2_image"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/row2_text"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/horizontal_barrier"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_confirm" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/row2_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/row2_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/horizontal_barrier"
        tools:text="Hello World" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

expected to be like below if the right text is too long. It can achieved by LinearLayout and RelativeLayout
[image]

Comment: can you post a picture of the desired result? from your wording  I can't understand what it is you want to achieve

Comment: @LenaBru I edited the question to elaborate more. Does it help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Kindly check the Constraintlayout version. Use `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` 
with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) to stop your text from expanding more than needed.

**let's take this layout for example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="longgggggg texttttttttttttttttexttttttttttttttttexttttttttttttttttexttttttttttttttt"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.18" />
```

And because of `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.18"` and  `android:layout_width="0dp"` on both text views the long textView will not exit its constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the problem was that I was mixing `left` and `start`, so the view was constrained from `Right to Left`, but the left was set as `constraintStartToParent`.

Changing everything to `start / end` solved the issue.